# How do I build a native binary on .NET Core using the current preview?

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli

Using the current .NET Core preview, how do I compile (Publish ?) a native binary for a console application. I am on Mac OS 10.11.

I did the following:

```
dotnet new
dotnet restore
dotnet publish
```

I kind of expected "publish" to build a native binary for me, but it did not. It places a .dll, along with some JSON, in the publish folder ? I should mention the application runs fine when using `dotnet run`.

So, how do I get a native binary for my simple console application ?

Comment: .NET Native is in the roadmap beyond RTM. They recently moved the CLI (dotnet.exe) tooling for native from the CLI project to the .NET Native project (https://github.com/dotnet/corert) ... no idea how the build is there currently.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to an MS dev on the Slack channel, native compilation was removed/disabled in RC2 since it wasn't deemed ready yet.

There does seem to be a little bit of interest in it, so I've been debating whether to try to get it running myself, from the CLI source.

Otherwise, we'll just have to wait, but I agree, huge disappointment.

EDIT: just for completeness, I should add that .NET Core and .NET Native are available for UWP / Windows Store apps, though obviously this is not cross-platform.

EDIT #2: since this seems to continue to be getting attention, the new way that this is planned on being done is [CoreRT](https://github.com/dotnet/corert), currently in active development.