# How to compile a Release configuration for Ubuntu console app .NET Core RC2

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, coreclr, .net-native

For example, the hwapp sample builds Debug but not Release:

```
$ dotnet new
…
$ dotnet restore
…
$ dotnet build
…
$ dotnet ./bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/hwapp.dll
Hello World!
```

What exactly do I have to add to this project.json to get an optimized build?

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

---

My original question may have conflated 2 difference issues - How do I build Release instead of Debug? How do I build with .NET Native?

I've just stumbled over [an answer to the first question](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/core-sdk/cli/dotnet-build.html#options):

```
$ dotnet build -c Release
```

That seems to provide a very obvious performance improvement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I build a native binary on .NET Core using the current preview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308118/how-do-i-build-a-native-binary-on-net-core-using-the-current-preview)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2803#issuecomment-216334290) **native** compilation has been removed from the latest version of the `dotnet` tools.